# Save console.log into a txt file

Tags: reactjs, console.log

I need help: I'm developing a fast food web app and one of the use case is to let the cousine know the status of orders. Now, I've managed to do it using SSE, and now I have to keep trace somehow of the active connections. My idea was to redirect the console.log outputs (i.e. "connection opened", "message arrived" etc) into a txt file, however if I use fs, like in nodejs, it doesn't work and gives me errors. Do you have any other suggestions? Or do you know how can I save the logs in a txt file?
I thank you all in advance

Comment: can you please provide the errors you had?

Comment: This seems like a weird solution to... well any problem. I can say that you can't generally write to files on the users machine, maybe local storage would be an option, but we need way more details.

Comment: the errors were that basically I couldn't use "const fs= require("fs")", and if I used import fs from 'fs' it said that was not found

Comment: what i wanted to do was basically redirect the console log to a file, and I've seen that in node is possible, however I'm using sse from node to react, not from node to node.


p.s.: if you have better ideas to keep track of connections let me know, all solutions are welcome